# Is this GIF correct about the dialogue of the scene? And what episode is it from?

Tags: okami-san-and-her-seven-companions

[A GIF of Okami-san](https://tenor.com/view/tsundere-heaven-anime-blushing-toradora-taiga-aisaka-gif-17476190) saying "Baka! Baka! Baka! Hmpf! I love you too."

It's labelled as Taiga of Toradora, but more searching indicates that it's Okami-san.

Is it accurate and where is it from?

Comment: trace.moe gives a timestamp of 06:39 in episode 1. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @蛞蝓真宵 - If the dialogue was accurate. Because a tsundere being so upfront about her love was slightly off to me. And I was right. The dialogue is not show-accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene comes from slightly before the 7th minute, approximately 06:39, and what Okami-san actually says is a response to Ringo teasing / asking her about her interest in Ryōshi.

Something like ["N-Not really! No way. No interest whatsoever."](https://youtu.be/LydNSU5nJ_A?t=412)